# Changing UIButton text after reload data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` in the `UICollectionView`, I want to change its text. But there is a problem, after clicking on it, collectionView reload its data, so the text will change for a second and then it comes back to the first one.

**Code:**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var showMorebtn: OButton!
 @IBAction func pressShowMoreBtn(_ sender: OButton) {
    askForChangingheightOfCell?()
    showMorebtn.setTitle("Show more", for: .normal)
    showMorebtn.setTitle("Show less", for: .highlighted)
```

I will be appreciated for your help in advance

Comment: You have to maintain state for changing title, means use one property (variable) in the view controller (or parent) and as per state, you can assign value to the button.

Comment: I dont know why here is 0Button! type instead of UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Declare a variable to store button state and based on that state change the button title

```
var isShowMore = false

func onButtonTapped(){
    isShowMore = !isShowMore

    if isShowMore{
        showMorebtn.setTitle("Show less", for: .highlighted)
    }else{
        showMorebtn.setTitle("Show more", for: .normal)
    }

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set your new title for `button` in `.selected` state instead of `.highlighted`

`UiButton` is only in `.highlighted` state when you clicked on `UiButton` then after `touchEnds` it back into `.normal` state, Then you've to define your change `title` code for `.selected`

e.g.

```
@IBOutlet weak var showMorebtn: OButton!

@IBAction func pressShowMoreBtn(_ sender: OButton) 
 {
    askForChangingheightOfCell?()
    showMorebtn.setTitle("Show more", for: .normal)
    showMorebtn.setTitle("Show less", for: .selected)
 }
```